# Buffer overflows when using sprintf assigning to char array with char pointer as one of the inputs

Tags: c++, printf, arrays, char-pointer

I use sprintf to create a char array that can later be written out as a call to the system.

```
char buffer[80];
char *ip = inet_ntoa(sa.sin_addr);
short port = 1;
sprintf(buffer, "Command with IP %s and port %d",ip, port);
system(buffer);
```

Now in theory this buffer should have plenty of space allocated for this string. But somehow, due to the char pointer, I still get `* stack smashing detected *` as an error.

Can't sprintf handle the char pointer as input, perhaps because it has a large allocation itself?

EDIT:

It turns out the buffer was to small after all, at least for some arguments.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`? And what are you really writing into the buffer? We can't test the "theory" that 80 bytes is enough if we don't know that.

Comment: First of all, use safe sprintf_s instead of sprintf. Secondly, make sure, that you are working on the valid type of strings (single-byte vs multibyte).

Comment: @Spook `sprintf_s` is a Microsoft-specific extension.  As he has not indicated which system he is compiling this for ...

Comment: I don't see any *C++* code here, the *C++* answer will be different from a *C* one.

Comment: @ZacHowland Ah, I see, I didn't know that. As I understand, there is no generally-available safe version of `sprintf`?

Comment: So, a `main` that contains nothing except that exact code causes a stack smash for you?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I have chosen a rather large value compared to the actual result string. Which still allowed to be printed. It gives an error afterwards.

Comment: @Spook There is correct.  There is no *portable* safe version of the s*f family of functions (`sprintf`, `sscanf`, `printf`, etc) in C.

Comment: @Oxidator: So what's the return value of `sprintf`? That will tell you exactly how many characters it wrote, so you can tell for sure whether or not that's causing the observed overrun. If the return value is less than 80, then something else is causing it.

Comment: try to check sprintf return value. it can tell you if you had overflowed the buffer (how many bytes you wrote). My suspicion is that it is not the problematic place.

Comment: 1. What does `inet_ntoa` return *exactly*? 2. Does *this specific code* crash too (I mean, with command placeholder instead of real command)? 3. Does this code crash if you increase size of buffer? (maybe it's not a matter of that sprintf). What is the border size of buffer below which it crashes for the code you cited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have C++ tagged, and not C, your code would be better written as:

```
std::string ip = "0.0.0.0";
int port = 1;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Command with IP:  " << ip << " and port " << port;
system(oss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: You are using legacy C language features which have been replaced by type-safe versions in C++.  If you are writing C++ code, you should always prefer the C++ language features over the legacy C language features.

Comment: Ok. Apart from that. Do you know what could go wrong with my legacy code sample?

Comment: It could be any number of things:  Your `buffer` may not be large enough.  The return value from `inet_ntoa` should be immediately copied as it is only valid until the next socket call (it returns the address of a static character array, or `NULL`).  Or it could be something else in your code that you haven't shown here.